# Failed to connect to api.dynadot.com using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm working on putting together something for a client that connects to the DynaDot API on a server. I have whitelisted the server IP address in their dashboard as well as my own private IP. When I make the call in a browser to the API, I do in fact get data returned, but when I make the call via the server/script, I get:

> Failed to connect to api.dynadot.com port 443: Connection timed out

When I attempt to use this code below, it's what gives me the results

```
  $url = 'https://api.dynadot.com/api3.xml?key=' . $dynadot->key . '&command=search&domain0=zebodog.info&show_price=1';

  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  #curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,100);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cert.pem');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAPATH, 'cert.pem');  

  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  echo curl_error($curl_handle);

  curl_close($curl_handle);
  if (empty($buffer)){
      print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
  }
  else{
      print $buffer;
  }
```

I'm curious as to what I am missing here. I can change the URL to be [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and it works fine, yet it won't return any data from DynaDot, yet, I can pull up the same URL in a browser and it works. DynaDot says that the IP is not blocked, and I have checked with the hosting company and they aren't rotating IPs or anything. So I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you telnet the port?

Comment: wget api.dynadot.com
--2019-05-20 15:45:09--  http://api.dynadot.com/
Resolving api.dynadot.com... 54.235.244.14
Connecting to api.dynadot.com|54.235.244.14|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.